# CakePHP Image Link

Tags: html, css, oop, cakephp

I can't find how a make this a link to my image in CakePHP:

```
  <img src="img/default.png" width="130" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 3; opacity: 0; ">



$html->image('default.png').....????;
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the following to the options array:

```
'url' => array('controller' => '..' 'action' => '..')
```

i.e.

```
$this->Html->image('default.png', array('url' => ..));
```

There's more information in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image)

Comment: Read the docs, it's as simple as adding 'style' in the options array.

Comment: @NDeveloper - if you "mean the style of the image", you should reference that somewhere in your question.  As it stands, Dunhamzzz has answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

echo $this->Html->image(BASE_URL."images/plus.jpg",array("alt" => 'add fields',"id"=>"add_more","height"=>40,"width"=>40));